# Adding address (newly-built house) to existing street on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, editing, address

How can I add my address (newly-built house) to an existing street on Google maps?

It shows on Bing maps OK but not on Google maps.

Existing answers to this question seem to be outdated.

Surely this is a common problem every time a new house is built.

Comment: Have you seen these threads [Add a missing place to the map](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [Need help adding my new address to google maps](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/2388635?hl=en)?

Comment: What are the "Existing answers to this question" that you mention?  Please always provide links when referring to earlier Q&As of this site.  It is always best to add/update answers to an old question rather than re-asking the same question.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?